# SqlDataReader connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

In my windows service, I am executing a stored procedure that selects the top 2500 rows from a table and returns the data to the service. I am catching the results using the `SqlDataReader` object.

My question is: does the `SqlDataReader` object return the 2500 rows to my service and store them in memory at one time and read each record one by one or does it read each record one by one from the stored procedure in SQL Server?

Thank you!

```
SqlCommand getData = new SqlCommand(adminConnectionString, adminConnection);

// Sets SqlCommand Information
getData.CommandText = adminDatabaseName + ".dbo.SprocToExecute";
getData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
getData.CommandTimeout = 300;

// Creates parameters, sets their values, and adds them to the SqlCommand
SqlParameter sessionIDParameter = new SqlParameter("@SessionID", SqlDbType.Int);
sessionIDParameter.Value = ID;
getData.Parameters.Add(sessionIDParameter);

SqlDataReader dataReader = getData.ExecuteReader();

if (dataReader.HasRows)
{
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH RECORD 
    }
}
```

Comment: It reads each record one by one from the connection stream (forward only). You get a strong hint also reading the docs:  _While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is busy serving the SqlDataReader, and no other operations can be performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it._

Answer (score 0):

The stored proc continues to serve rows until the end of the "while (dataReader.Read())" loop.

Use SqlDataAdapter if you want to get all rows at once

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(getData);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
```

The stored proc starts and finishes upon execution of "adapter.Fill(dt)"

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlDataReader` object will only store one row at a time in memory.  Upon calling the `ExecuteReader()` method of a `SqlCommand` object an unbuffered stream of data is created to sequentially process the incoming record.  However if you're looking to have all of the rows read into memory at once this can be done by using a `SqlDataAdapter` object.  This will load all records satisfying the query into memory once the `Fill` method is called.  On a side note, make sure to always call the `Close()` method of the `SqlDataReader` object once you're finished using it.  Not closing this can have implications, for example if output parameters are used these cannot be accessed until the `SqlDataReader` is closed.  The connection (`adminConnection` in your code) used by the `SqlDataReader` object exclusively belongs to this reader when the reader is opened and subsequent commands, or other `SqlDataReader` objects, cannot use this connection until it the  `SqlDataReader` is closed through the `Close()` method.